# How to merge column heading in Rdlc report

Tags: c#

Here the "year" heading is repeated thrice I need to merge them into one. Do I need to change settings of the cell?

Can I merge them into one. Please note that the year column is grouped one

Current output is,

```
                  || Year|| Year|| Year||
Territory||Country|| 2001|| 2002|| 2003||
Asia      | India | 5645  | 64611| 6464| 
          |Japan  | 6543  | 4648 | 5548| 
Europe   ........................
```

Expected output is

```
      ||        Year       ||
Territory||Country|| 2001|| 2002|| 2003||
Asia      | India | 5645  | 64611| 6464| 
          |Japan  | 6543  | 4648 | 5548| 
Europe   ........................
```

"Year" should not repeat

Answer (score 0):

Add a blank (empty string) column parent group to the existing Column Year group, and align the text to center.

hope it helps.